# Can I stream media from a Windows partition?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, streaming, media, plex

I have Windows 7 installed on my desktop. I have 2 hard drives. My operating system is on one and the other is media storage (NTFS). My family regularly streams media (using PLEX) to multiple devices in my house. I want to install Ubuntu on my primary drive so I can dual boot. If I do so, and I am booted into Ubuntu, assuming I have PLEX installed under Ubuntu, will my family still be able to stream the media from the NTFS media drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plex can use your local computer as a media server.  Your details sounds like you are already running Plex under Windows which is serving the media from the attached drives.

You can do the same thing if you install Plex to Ubuntu.  Ubuntu will be your server.  The devices is unaware of the server operating system.  It just receives the media streams from the server.

You can mount your NTFS media drives under Ubuntu and run the Plex server under Ubuntu no different from the way you're currently running it under Windows.